# C++ hex format string

Tags: c++, formatting, hex

The `Create` method should produce a string of 9 chars composed in this way:
`som` followed by `id` char plus 4 chars (hex string representing `value`) plus 2 chars (hex string representing crc) plus eom char.
This's the code:

```
private: 
     char som = '$';
     char eom = '&';
     bool crc = true;

unsigned char checksum(string data) {
    unsigned char sum = 0x00;

    for (char &c : data)
        sum += c;

    return sum;
}

string epilogue(string data) {
    ostringstream _message;

    if (crc) {
        byte _sum = checksum(data);
        _message << std::hex << (_sum & 0xFF);
    }

    _message << eom;

    return _message.str();
}

string Create(char id, short value) {
    ostringstream _message, _data;

    _data << std::hex << (value & 0xFFFF);

    _message << som << id << _data.str() << epilogue(_data.str());

    return _message.str();
}
```

The problem is in this line:

```
_data << std::hex << (value & 0xFFFF);
```

that correctly outputs an hex string but not of the *correct* length.
Similar problem should be in the line:

```
_message << std::hex << (_sum & 0xFF);
```

How can I fix this code to produce exactly the pattern I need?
In Java I was using something like this:

```
String.format("%02X", value & 0xFFFF)
```

EDIT (runnable code):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

typedef unsigned char byte;

class PacketBuilder {
private: 
    char som = '$';
    char eom = '&';
    bool crc = true;

public:
    PacketBuilder(const char som, const char eom, bool crc) {
        this->som = som;
        this->eom = eom;
        this->crc = crc;
    }

    byte checksum(string data) {
        byte sum = 0x00;

        for (char &c : data)
            sum += c;

        return sum;
    }

    string epilogue(string data) {
        ostringstream _message;

        if (crc) {
            byte _sum = checksum(data);
            _message << std::hex << (_sum & 0xFF);
        }

        _message << eom;

        return _message.str();
    }

    string Create(char id, short value) {
        ostringstream _message, _data;

        _data << std::hex << (value & 0xFFFF);

        _message << som << id << _data.str() << epilogue(_data.str());

        return _message.str();
    }
};

int main() {
    PacketBuilder* _pb = new PacketBuilder('$','&',true);

    string _packet = _pb->Create('C',0);

    cout << _packet;

    return 0;
}
```

[Online code](https://onlinegdb.com/H1cxn_9UI)

Expected result is:

```
$C0000c0&
```

Comment: `private char som = '$';` is not valid c++, is this a typo or is it not c++?

Comment: Personally I would use `sprintf` which will be similar to the Java solution. But if you want to do it the C++ way then use `std::setw` and `std::setfill` to left pad your output with zeros.

Comment: @idclev463035818 yes it was a cut & paste from the wrong source (I'm converting this from Java) i fixed it right now.

Comment: in any case you should post a [mcve] and expected and desired output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `std::setw` and `std::setfill` in C++.

Remember to save and restore iomanip flags.

```
string epilogue(string data) {
    ostringstream _message;

    if (crc) {
        byte _sum = checksum(data);
        const auto save = _message.flags();
        _message << std::hex << std::setw(2) 
            << std::setfill('0') << (_sum & 0xFF);
        _message.flags(save);
    }

    _message << eom;

    return _message.str();
}

string Create(char id, short value) {
    ostringstream _message, _data;

    const auto save = _data.flags();
    _data << std::hex << std::setw(4) 
            << std::setfill('0') << (value & 0xFFFF);
        _message.flags(save);

    _message << som << id << _data.str() << epilogue(_data.str());

    return _message.str();
}
```

:

```
format("%02X",
           ^ std::hex << std::uppercase
          ^ std::setw(2)
         ^ std::setfill('0')
```